# How To: Change Apache Default Directory | Multiple Domains

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, https, http, apache2

**Problem**: I am working on a production server hosting multiple domains and I am unable to get each domain's index.html to load.  The default Apache page is loading instead.

Example, Apache is not loading hello world from `/var/www/thepowerhousemethod.org/public_html/index.html`

I don't get it because the DocumentRoot looks fine.  Here are the details of the scenario on this production server.

00-default.conf in `/etc/httpd/conf.d` says DocumentRoot is `/var/www/`  This should load all the domains public_html files in `/var/www/thepowerhousemethod.org/public_html/index.html` but apache isn't.  Instead Apache is loading `/var/www/html/index.html`.

/etc/httpd/conf shows the document root as DocumentRoot "/var/www/"

The domain in question is thepowerhousemethod.org and should be showing `/var/www/thepowerhousemethod.org/public_html/index.html`

I'm just not seeing the solution.

Here is all the relevant information for the server.

[root@orcacomputers public_html]# cat index.html

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
        <head>
                <title>The Powerhouse Method</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <h1>What is up my mizzan bro?</h1>
        </body>
</html>
```

[root@orcacomputers public_html]# pwd

```
/var/www/thepowerhousemethod.org/public_html
```

The configuration file is:

[root@orcacomputers conf.d]# cat thepowerhousemethod.org.conf

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
           
            ServerName thepowerhousemethod.org.conf
            ServerAlias www.thepowerhousemethod.org
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            DocumentRoot /var/www/thepowerhousemethod.org/public_html
            ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/thepowerhousemethod.org-error.log
            CustomLog /var/log/httpd/thepowerhousemethod.org-access.log combined
     
     
            <Directory "/var/www/thepowerhousemethod.org/public_html">
              AllowOverride All
            </Directory>
               
</VirtualHost>
```

[root@orcacomputers conf]# cat httpd.conf

```
#
# This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/> for detailed information.
# In particular, see
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directives.html>
# for a discussion of each configuration directive.
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
#
# Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
# of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
# server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
# with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so 'log/access_log'
# with ServerRoot set to '/www' will be interpreted by the
# server as '/www/log/access_log', where as '/log/access_log' will be
# interpreted as '/log/access_log'.
 
#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
# ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to specify a local disk on the
# Mutex directive, if file-based mutexes are used.  If you wish to share the
# same ServerRoot for multiple httpd daemons, you will need to change at
# least PidFile.
#
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
 
#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80
 
#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
#
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
#
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
 
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User apache
Group apache
 
# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#
 
#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#
ServerAdmin root@localhost
 
#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
#ServerName www.example.com:80
 
#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
 
#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#
 
#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
**DocumentRoot** "`/var/www/`"
 
#
# Relax access to content within /var/www.
#
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>
 
# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 
    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None
 
    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
 
#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>
 
#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
 
#
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
 
#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn
 
<IfModule log_config_module>
    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    #
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
 
    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
 
    #
    # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
    # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
    # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
    # logged therein and *not* in this file.
    #
    #CustomLog "logs/access_log" common
 
    #
    # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
    # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
    #
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>
 
<IfModule alias_module>
    #
    # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to
    # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client
    # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
    # Example:
    # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.example.com/bar
 
    #
    # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
    # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
    # Example:
    # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
    #
    # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
    # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
    # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
    # the filesystem path.
 
    #
    # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts.
    # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
    # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
    # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
    # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
    # directives as to Alias.
    #
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
 
</IfModule>
 
#
# "/var/www/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
 
<IfModule mime_module>
    #
    # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
    # filename extension to MIME-type.
    #
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
 
    #
    # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
    # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
    #
    #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    #
    # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
    # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
    #
    #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    #
    # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
    # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
    #
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
 
    #
    # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
    # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
    # or added with the Action directive (see below)
    #
    # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
    # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
 
    # For type maps (negotiated resources):
    #AddHandler type-map var
 
    #
    # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
    #
    # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
    # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>
 
#
# Specify a default charset for all content served; this enables
# interpretation of all content as UTF-8 by default.  To use the
# default browser choice (ISO-8859-1), or to allow the META tags
# in HTML content to override this choice, comment out this
# directive:
#
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
 
<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    #
    # The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
    # contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
    # directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
    #
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>
 
#
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
#
 
#
# EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it,
# memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall may be used to deliver
# files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
# be turned off when serving from networked-mounted
# filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
# broken on your system.
# Defaults if commented: EnableMMAP On, EnableSendfile Off
#
#EnableMMAP off
EnableSendfile on
 
# Supplemental configuration
#
# Load config files in the "/etc/httpd/conf.d" directory, if any.
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

[root@orcacomputers conf]# pwd
/etc/httpd/conf

[root@orcacomputers html]# httpd -S

```
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/orcacomputers.com/public_html] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/orcamartialarts.com/public_html] does not exist
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  orcacomputers.orcainbox (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:56)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server orcacomputers.orcainbox (/etc/httpd/conf.d/00-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost orcacomputers.orcainbox (/etc/httpd/conf.d/00-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost 0rcan0mic.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/0rcan0mic.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.0rcan0mic.com
         port 80 namevhost constantcounselling.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/constantcounselling.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.constantcounselling.com
         port 80 namevhost couponfreegiveaway.com.conf (/etc/httpd/conf.d/couponfreegiveaway.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.couponfreegiveaway.com.conf
         port 80 namevhost freeonlinemoney.net (/etc/httpd/conf.d/freeonlinemoney.net.conf:1)
                 alias www.freeonlinemoney.net
         port 80 namevhost greatresultsbusinesscoaching.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/greatresultsbusinesscoaching.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.greatresultsbusinesscoaching.com
         port 80 namevhost hopetonmedia.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/hopetonmedia.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.hopetonmedia.com
         port 80 namevhost internetpowerhouse.org (/etc/httpd/conf.d/internetpowerhouse.org.conf:1)
                 alias www.internetpowerhouse.org
         port 80 namevhost jessemacdougall.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/jessemacdougall.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.jessemacdougall.com
         port 80 namevhost macdougall.ninja (/etc/httpd/conf.d/macdougall.ninja.conf:1)
                 alias www.macdougall.ninja
         port 80 namevhost martial-arts-of-health.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/martial-arts-of-health.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.martial-arts-of-health.com
         port 80 namevhost mybestfriendsarecats.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/mybestfriendsarecats.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.mybestfriendsarecats.com
         port 80 namevhost orcaaccounting.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/orcaaccounting.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.orcaaccounting.com
         port 80 namevhost orcacomputres.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/orcacomputers.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.orcacomputers.com
         port 80 namevhost 0rcan0mic.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/orcahelpdesk.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.0rcan0mic.com
         port 80 namevhost orcainbox.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/orcainbox.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.orcainbox.com
         port 80 namevhost orcamartialarts.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/orcamartialarts.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.orcamartialarts.com
         port 80 namevhost themartialartsofmoney.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/themartialartsofmoney.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.themartialartsofmoney.com
         port 80 namevhost `thepowerhousemethod.org.conf (/etc/httpd/conf.d/thepowerhousemethod.org.conf:1)`
                 alias `www.thepowerhousemethod.org`
         port 80 namevhost womenwhohelpmen.org (/etc/httpd/conf.d/womenwhohelpmen.org.conf:1)
                 alias www.womenwhohelpmen.org
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
`Main DocumentRoot`: "`/var/www/`"
Main ErrorLog: "/etc/httpd/logs/error_log"
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/run/httpd/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
PidFile: "/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: _RH_HAS_HTTPPROTOCOLOPTIONS
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="apache" id=48
Group: name="apache" id=48
```

[root@orcacomputers html]# systemctl status httpd
●

```
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: **active** (**running**) since Fri 2020-10-09 22:21:32 PDT; 14min ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 24252 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 24266 (httpd)
   Status: "Total requests: 65; Current requests/sec: 0; Current traffic:   0 B/sec"
    Tasks: 11
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           ├─24266 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─24268 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─24269 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─24270 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─24274 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─24276 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─24321 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─24360 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─24370 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─24371 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           └─24996 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
 
Oct 09 22:21:32 orcacomputers.orcainbox systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Oct 09 22:21:32 orcacomputers.orcainbox httpd[24266]: AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/orca...ist
Oct 09 22:21:32 orcacomputers.orcainbox httpd[24266]: AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/orca...ist
Oct 09 22:21:32 orcacomputers.orcainbox php-mapi[24266]: PHP-Mapi instantiated 7,1,14,51822
Oct 09 22:21:32 orcacomputers.orcainbox systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Oct 09 22:22:15 orcacomputers.orcainbox httpd[24362]: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
Oct 09 22:22:16 orcacomputers.orcainbox httpd[24363]: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
Oct 09 22:22:17 orcacomputers.orcainbox httpd[24368]: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
Oct 09 22:27:07 orcacomputers.orcainbox httpd[24369]: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: For starters, the `ServerName` should not be `ServerName thepowerhousemethod.org.conf`

Comment: in fact i believe that .conf is a conf file and servername is a regular domain name and not to read files

Comment: Bingo! That's it! *facepalm* Thank you gentlemen! =)